# Can I use custome components created in flex in flash project?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, custom-component

I created flash project in flash builder and a flash component project and then created a spark component in flex component project. When I tried to add the custom component in the flash it thrown error

```
//code
this.addChild(new TestComp);
//compilation error
1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type TestComp to an unrelated type flash.display:DisplayObject.   Main.as /pw3d/src   line 35 Flex Problem
```

Is it possible to use flex components in flash at all? Is there a work around?

Comment: @TimofeiDavydik I would have vote up if this was youtube :)

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to use flex components in flash at all?

Yes, it is possible, in theory, but I expect it to be tedious and difficult.  You'll have to do all your framework initialization manually.  That means you'll have to do things like setup the [SystemManager](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/managers/SystemManager.html) class manually.

Honestly, I don't know everything that the Flex Compiler / Application tag does to setup the Flex Framework.  You may have to compile a simple Flex app with the 'keep' attribute and review the generated code to make sure you mimic that in your Flash Pro code.

Some reference information can be found [here](http://blogs.adobe.com/rgonzalez/2006/06/modular_applications_part_1.html), [here](http://blogs.adobe.com/rgonzalez/2006/06/modular_applications_part_2.html), and [here](http://guyinthechair.com/2010/01/understanding-the-flex-systemmanager/).

The error you're seeing is odd; because a Flex Component must extend UIComponent and UIComponent extends DisplayObject.  I wonder if you are missing a SWC library in your class path somehow and Flash pro is unable to tell that TestComp is actually a DisplayObject.